# Google Chrome error help CSS error

Tags: css, google-chrome, cloud9-ide, semantic-ui

I have been getting an error from Google chrome saying
: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 404 error.

I linked the path to the correct folder in cloud 9 project, but there is another project with the same format as my current one and it works fine. I am also using Semantic ui does that have anything to do with it?

The error code:

> https://job-ayub.c9users.io/stylesheets/main.css resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

On the other project I got a similar error and I easily fixed it by changing the link to href="/sylesheets/main.css"> Then the error was handled and everything was fine until I opened a new project and tried the same fix but it didn't work.

```
<html>
     <head>
          <title></title>
          <link rel="stylesheets" text="type/css" href="stylesheets/main.css">

    </head>
        <body>
         </body>
```

css use to be so easy with sublime why is it different with C9.io ?

Comment: What is the path it is looking for. What do you get when you point your browser towards that path. Does this path match what you have in your code. Please post all information you have.

Comment: Sorry, but this question tells us none of the details we need to help you out.  At this point all I can tell is that your server is telling you it can't find the file.  Not very helpful I'm afraid.

Comment: Without more information, it appears that you are just incorrectly referencing your css file. Have a look this post to better understand relative file paths: [Quick Reminder About File Paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/).

Comment: Okay thanks for your help I'll take a look at my path again using your web link. Jack

Answer (score 1):

Okay I solved the problem if you are using express and node.js you should use app.use(express.static('_dirname')); in you app.js file. Simply creating a path directly to the css file will not connect to the express server and you will get an 404 error.